# Macbook doesn't stay asleep when lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have a 2006 Macbook running Snow Leopard. I suddenly noticed that my computer's battery would be at a different level when I woke it up than it was when I closed the lid to put it to sleep.  After leaving it on a table next to my bed a few times, I realized that my computer was randomly waking up (evidenced by the Apple logo lighting up) when it was laying on a flat, level surface with nothing on top of it or anything touching it.  I tried switching the settings so that I have to click the "sleep" option in the menu rather than relying on it to automatically go to sleep when the lid is closed, but the problem persists.  Why won't my Macbook stay asleep?

Comment: Have you tried to disable waking for network access in the energy saver preferences?

Comment: @LauriRanta I've had this problem, too, and not been able to find a solution. This continues happening even with waking for network access disabled.

Comment: Having fought some Genius-stumping sleep issues, I can tell you there's no one cause and one solution for all sleep problems. Assuming it's not [expected behavior](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), watch Console after the next wake and give us a 'wake reason'. Also an OS version.

Comment: do the logs say anything that could be of help? They usually do for sleep related issues. Look for them using Console.app

Comment: Same problem.  I was forced to give up sleep mode and do a full shutdown when not using it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that the sensor to detect lid opening can trigger by mistake. If so, you can disable it by going into Terminal.app and typing:

```
sudo pmset -a lidwake 0
```

Note that this means the Mac will no longer automatically wake when you open it. Instead you would need a key press or mouse click to wake.

Answer (score 0):

What network sharing settings do you have enabled? I found that enabled internet, file or printer sharing will prevent full sleep.